# why does matlab give me a negative number?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matlab

I have the following problem

A steel company has four different types of scrap metal (called Typ-1 to Typ-4) with
the following compositions per unit of volume

[image]

They need to determine the volumes to blend from each type of scrap metal so that
the resulting mixture has the following amounts of Al, Si, C, and Fe:
Al - 9 , Si - 6 , C - 8.0 , Fe - 190.0.
Determine volumes of each the 4 scrap metals Typ-1, Typ-2, Typ-3, Typ-4 to blend in
order to reach the desired amounts of Al, Si, C, Fe. Formulate the system and solve it
using matlab (’back-slash’).

However when I go to Matlab,  I am using Octave, and enter the following commands

m = [5 3 4 88; 7 6 5 82; 2 1 3 94; 1 2 1 96]
R = [9;6;8;190]

> > m\R
> >     ans =

22.6980
   18.6980
  -90.7020
    2.2980

How can the amount for type3 be negative?

Comment: try m' \ R instead. m' is the same as transpose(m) -- for real matrices

Comment: I get ans =0.982000\n0.370000\n 0.722000\n0.056000 but when I do m * ans with that I do not get back the original answers. Not really even close.

Comment: m \ R answers the question: which combination of columns of m gives R. But you want to combine rows (Typ-1 -- Typ-4); hence the transpose. Of course, m * ans won't give you R, since you are again combining columns instead of rows.

Comment: Using http://reduce-algebra.com/ I get $\frac{491}{500}$, $\frac{37}{100}$, $\frac{361}{500}$, $\frac{7}{125}$ which is the same as what you already got $0.982$, $0.37$, $0.722$, $0.056$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about how to type in correct commands in a particular program, and not about mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to solve the system $mx = R$. That is nonsensical because you are not adding together columns of the matrix $m$. Try solving $m^Tx = R$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Goal**

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a map between the $m=4$ material types and $n=4$ metals.

The fraction of the $m=4$ types (I-IV) is $f$. The relative abundance or parts of the $n=4$ elements is $p$.

Blend $m=4$ type to get a material with composition $a$.

**Data**

$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A} f &= p \\
%
 \left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 5 & 7 & 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 6 & 1 & 2 \\
 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\
 88 & 82 & 94 & 96 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f_{1} \\
 f_{2} \\
 f_{3} \\
 f_{4} \\
\end{array}
\right) 
%
&=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 9 \\
 6 \\
 8 \\
 190 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 9 \text{ parts Al} \\
 6 \text{ parts Si} \\
 8 \text{ parts C } \\
 190 \text{ parts Fe} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
%
$$

---

**Solution**

$$
%
\begin{align}
% 
 f &= \mathbf{A}^{-1} p \\
%
 &= 
\frac{1}{500}
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 607 & -393 & -493 & 7 \\
 -255 & 245 & 245 & -5 \\
 -403 & 97 & 497 & -3 \\
 56 & 56 & -244 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 9 \\
 6 \\
 8 \\
 190 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
%
&= 
\frac{1}{500}
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 491 \\ 185 \\ 361 \\ 28 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
%
$$