# Potting soil problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider a company that specializes in potting soil. Each bag of potting soil for seedlings requires 2 units of sand, 1 unit of loam, and 1 unit of peat moss. Each bag of potting soil for general potting requires 1 unit of sand, 2 units of loam, and 1 unit of peat moss. Each bag of potting soil for hardwood plants requires 2 units of sand, 2 units of loam, and 2 units of peat moss. Find the numbers of bags of the three types of potting soil that the company can produce with the given amounts of raw materials.

They have a total of 1000 units of sand, 800 units of loam, and 700 units of peat moss.

---

I have absolutely no idea how to go about answering this problem. Could someone please give me some pointer? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: Does the problem require to consider each type individually, for example, we could produce $500$ bags for seedlings, $400$ bags for general potting and $350$ bags for hardwood plants, or does it require to find maximum number of bags of the three types when the total amount is shared among the types? The former is trivial, while the latter is more interesting to consider.

Comment: Have a look at a similar problem here: https://softmath.com/algebra-word-problems/show.php?id=18687

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting? OP clearly doesn't have experience with mathematical models. Is this off-topic, does it lack context, motivation or what? Perhaps it does, but I'm not sure that if the same problem were reworded as something like "maximize sum given the system of inequalities" these trigger-happy people wouldn't go point hunting, even if the question lacked context as the one as stated here.

Comment: The answers below do not maximize total number of bags. Maximal number of bags is $600$: $400$ of seedlings, $200$ of general bags and $0$ hardwood bags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let S be the bags of potting soil for seedlings, G be the potting soil for general potting, and H be the potting soil for hardwood  plants.

Each bag of seedling soil needs $2$ units of sand, each bag of general soil needs $1$ unit of sand, and each bag of hardwood soil needs $2$ units of sand. We have $1000$ units of sand.

We can  say $2S+G+2H=1000$. -- (1)

By similar logic for units of loam and peat moss, we get the equations

$S+2G+2H=800$. -- (2)

$S+G+2H=700$. -- (3)

By subtracting (3) from (2), we get $G=100$.

This means that there are $100$ bags of general soil produced.

We plug this in to get new equations.

$2S+2H=900$ (1)

$S+2H=600$ (2)

$S+2H=600$ (3)

Now, we subtract (2) from (1), we get $S=300$

This means that there are $300$ bags of seedling soil produced.

We plug this into equation (2)

$300 + 2H = 600$.

Therefore $H=150$, so there are $150$ bags of hardwood soil produced.

Finally, we have $100$ bags of general soil, $300$ bags of seedling soil, and $150$ bags of hardwood soil.

$\boxed{(S,G,H)=(300,100,150)}$

---

Notice: This solution seems complicated, but if you practice a few problems and come back to this, this entire process should take you no more than $15$ seconds, I ASSURE you.

Comment: Thank you, this helped immensely :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve a 3x3 sistem of ecuations ( 3 unknowns and 3 ecuations)
I suggest you use the number of each bag as the unknown. 
That is x = number of potting soils for seedlings, y = ... , z = ... 
Try this and then try to relate x,y,z with the raw materials you would use.

You will get :
2x+y+2z=1000,
x+2y+2z=800,
x+y+2z = 700 ,

Which solving by your method of choice: 
x = 300,
y = 100,
z = 150,

Note:The solution is unique.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment at most.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the community ; I though we could post hints, anyway i finished the problem for it to be an answer ( and i m not allowed to comment yet ), so i will tell yo here that maybe the down voted because the solution is unique , that means that there is not point in finding max or min ( the total amount its shared between the tipes )

Comment: Giving hints is at times the best approach, but they should be given with some confidence that it would lead OP to correct answer. Advising someone to use $x,y,z$ as unknowns in a mathematical model is as vague as it gets. Your edit is more constructive, though,

Comment: But i didn´t just said to use x,y,z i said which things you should name x,y,z to try to solve the problem, in this types of problems its usually the "hard" part. Although maybe a made it too vague , i will try to expand a bit more in the future:)

Comment: I disagree that the "hard" part is to name the three things you want to know $x,y,z$. The hard part is to relate those three unknowns and that is what your edit does, while the former version didn't. Your effort is appreciated, though, and it will lead you far in this community. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

### Data

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{sand} \\
 \text{loam} \\
 \text{peat} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1000 \\
  800 \\
  700 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

---

### Solution

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{sand} \\
 \text{loam} \\
 \text{peat} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left(
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\right)^{-1}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1000 \\
  800 \\
  700 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 2 & 0 & -2 \\
 0 & 2 & -2 \\
 -1 & -1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1000 \\
  800 \\
  700 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  300 \\
  500 \\
  700 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

---

Another example of this problem is in [why does matlab give me a negative number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646910/why-does-matlab-give-me-a-negative-number/2275754#2275754)

Comment: This seems wrong. Firstly, it's not $10000$, $8000$ and $7000$ but order of magnitude less. On the other hand, what does $2sand + 1 loam+2peat = 10000$ even mean?!